# Repeated root case for ay''+by'+cy=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To solve the ODE $a y''(t)+b y'(t) +c y(t) = 0$, where $a,b,c$ are constant, we solve the characteristic equation $ar^{2}+br+c=0$. In the case when the roots are two repeated roots, i.e,. $r=r_{1}=r_{2}$, we get two linearly independent solutions $y_{1}(t)=e^{r_{1}t}$ and $y_{2}(t)= t e^{r_{1}}$.

I understand that the solution $y_{2}(t)= t e^{r_{1}}$ works and there are several approaches to get this solution, as mentioned in a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206967/history-of-the-double-root-solution-of-aybycy-0), and in the textbook by Boyce and DiPrima also shows three approaches, see: [image].

I do not have questions about these approaches. My question is, all these approaches require some computation. Is there any way to show $t e^{r_{1}}$ is a solution, without any computation? Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm taking your question as asking "Why does there have to be 2 solutions?"

If you have taken a Linear Algebra course then you could see the differential equation as asking for a basis for the eigenspace. Your solutions to the characteristic equation are your eigenvalues and your solutions to the DE are your eigenfunctions.

Since the DE is second order you know that you have a two dimensional space, and you need two linearly independent solutions to form a basis for the space.

The characteristic equation only gives one solution so you need to find the other.

We then assume that the other solution, $y_2$, is of the form $f(t)y_1(t)$ and then compute $f(t)$

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not my question. I understand there should be two linearly independent solutions, and I know how to find the second solution. My question is, as posted, "intuitively speaking, why $ te^{r_{1}t}$ should be a solution.

Comment: To put it differently, my question is, "is there a way to show $t e^{r_{1}}t$ is a solution, without any computation?". Thank you.

Comment: All we are doing is making a guess as to the form of the other solution, and then determining what conditions would give us a solution. Seems pretty intuitive to me.

Comment: Can you show f(t) = t without any computation?

Comment: Something can be intuitive and still require computation.

Comment: The word "intuitively" might not mean the same for everyone. I have rephrased my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're just looking for something to convince you that this is true, just think back to when you first did taylor series. You wanted the terms to be linearly independent so for each coefficient, $c_n$, you multiplied it by $x^n$

So your Taylor Series would be

$$c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+...+c_nx^n$$

You will see a similar pattern occur with your repeated roots

If the root $r_1$ is repeated n times your solutions would be:

$$c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2te^{r_1t}+c_3t^2e^{r_1t}+...+c_nt^{n-1}e^{r_1t}$$