# If the characteristic equation of a second ODE has a double root, why do we have to introduce $xe^{rx}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$f''(x)+bf'(x)+cf(x)=0.$$

So, we are looking for solution of the form $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$. If we replace this in the ODE, we get $$\lambda ^2+b\lambda +c=0.$$
Suppose this equation has a double root, i.e. $\lambda ^2+b\lambda +c=(\lambda -r)^2.$

Now, we know that solution are of the form $$f(x)=(A+Bx)e^{rx}.$$

---

How did we have the idea to consider $xe^x$ ? (because in the case where $\Delta =b^2-4c\neq 0$, i.e. $\lambda ^2+b\lambda +x=(\lambda -r_1)(\lambda -r_2)$, then solution are naturally of the form $$Ae^{r_1x}+Be^{r_2x},$$
where $r_i$ are real or complex depending on the context). So, indeed, if it has a double root, then $$Ae^{rx}+Be^{rx}=De^{rx},$$
and since the set of solution is a vector space of dimension $2$, then we must have an other linearly independent solution. So, how did we think to $xe^{rx}$ ? This comes a bit from nowhere for me. Any idea ?

Comment: It comes from linear algebra, it's called a generalized eigenvector.

Comment: From the DE side, it's also known as variation of parameters.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206967/history-of-the-double-root-solution-of-aybycy-0

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a less tricky guess for the second solution may be of form $f(x) = h(x)e^{rx}$
Plug this in the ode and you will get $h''(x)=0$
Or watch Sal showing the same [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/second-order-differential-equations/complex-roots-characteristic-equation/v/repeated-roots-of-the-characteristic-equation)